# Query to update the records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to sql and trying to build query where I need to update records for below scenario :

Scenario i)

| Domain | Schema | Table | sme | prodct name | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | sample_t | test | busy@gmail.com | xyz | yes |
| abc | sample | test | busy@gmail.com |  | yes |
| cde | sample1_t | test | test@gmail.com |  | yes |
| cde | sample1 | test | test@gmail.com | klm | yes |
| fgh | sample2_t | test1 | test1@gmail.com |  | yes |
| fgh | sample2 | test1 | test1@gmail.com |  | yes |

so need to build query if schema first part with(**_t**) and view **without(_t)** is equal(sample=sample) and (sample1=sample1) and tablename is equal and flag=yes and product name in present in table or view record then populate the same for other record as well.If both are null like for schema sample2 both are null then keep it as it is no updates.

Output:

| Domain | Schema | Table | sme | prodct name | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | sample_t | test | busy@gmail.com | xyz | yes |
| abc | sample | test | busy@gmail.com | xyz | yes |
| cde | sample1_t | test | test@gmail.com | klm | yes |
| cde | sample1 | test | test@gmail.com | klm | yes |
| fgh | sample2_t | test1 | test1@gmail.com |  | yes |
| fgh | sample2 | test1 | test1@gmail.com |  | yes |

I have tried updating table:

```
set product_name
where regexp_replace(upper(regexp_replace(col_data.schemaname, '^\s+|\s+$'::text, ''::text, 'g'::text)), '_t\s*$' as schemaview 
where schemaview=schema and table=table and product_name is not null
```

but its not correct/working.

Scenario 2 :

Input :

| Domain | Schema | Table | sme | prodct name | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | sample_t | test | busy@gmail.com | xyz | No |
|  | sample | test |  |  | No |
|  | sample1_t | test |  |  | No |
| cde | sample1 | test | test@gmail.com | klm | No |
| ghi | sample2 | test_2 | test_2@gmail.com | nop | No |
| ghi | sample2_t | test_2 | test_2@gmail.com | nop | No |

Output:

| Domain | Schema | Table | sme | prodct name | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | sample_t | test | busy@gmail.com | xyz | No |
| abc | sample | test | busy@gmail.com | xyz | No |
| cde | sample1_t | test | test@gmail.com | klm | No |
| cde | sample1 | test | test@gmail.com | klm | No |
| ghi | sample2 | test_2 | test_2@gmail.com | nop | No |
| ghi | sample2_t | test_2 | test_2@gmail.com | nop | No |

In this scenario if table and schema are same and flag=No then populate the value where its null. In this one I am not sure how to populate it as _t and without _t are in same field so not sure how to use joining codition.If its already populated or if in case of nulls in both case then no updates required

Comment: Do you want to update one or multiple columns ?

Comment: Do empty cells have Empty string or null ?

Comment: @sumant: update multiple columns and it's null.

Comment: Hi @SumantKumarMandal - I need to add one more scenario where if the domain is tbd and other domain has relevant value example abc , then I need to populate abc as domain in tbd..Colesce will work for not null scenario but in this scenario what condition should i write.And also can you please explain your code for my understanding purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed, your update requirement is independent of column *flag*.
We can apply SELF JOIN on table with proper filter expression to update data. When current value is *NULL*, update with another value. When both values are *NULL*, replacing one *NULL* with another *NULL* will not change anything.

```
UPDATE MyTable t1
SET productname = COALESCE(t1.productname,t2.productname),
    sme = COALESCE(t1.sme,t2.sme),
    domain = COALESCE(t1.domain,t2.domain)
FROM MyTable t2
WHERE (CONCAT(t1.schema,'_t')=t2.schema OR t1.schema=CONCAT(t2.schema,'_t')) 
AND t1.tablee = t2.tablee;
```

We can check my query and execution on [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/knryGYkC)

Comment: You should use `COALESCE` rather than those `CASE WHEN` expressions to improve the readability.

Comment: Thanks @JonasMetzler I have updated my answer with  your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you Sumant,question : in the where clause where concatenation condition is present,can you please help me in understanding how this is working when you do self join between t1 and t2.